# How to change a value in PHP based on the day of the month

Tags: php, date

is there a simple way to change a variable for example `$value='abcdef'` to another value `$value= 'ghijkl'` in PHP based on the date/day of the month ?

So if it's for example the 15th or 20th of a month the value should change from "abcdef" to "ghijkl".

I would be glad if someone could help out.

Comment: Yes, this is easy actually. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: since I have no idea I didn't try out anything. I just found some things about time stamps but that's all and I don't know what to do with it

Comment: The thing to do is to try it out and come back to use when your problem is more specific.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Too bad everyone is eager to give easy answers on easy questions to get all the rep. The OP won't learn from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `date()` function in php to extract a certain part of the current date. The `'j'` selection option selects the day of the month ([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)).

You can use a switch case or if statements to perform actions on this parameter, like so:

```
$value = 'abcdef';
if(date('j') == '15') {
    $value = 'ghjkl';
}
```

Or by:

```
$value = 'abcdef';
switch(date('j')) {
    case '20':
    case '15':
        $value = 'ghjkl';
        break;
}
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard sorry for that... was expecting some level of knowledge... I have ammended the answer with an explanation

Comment: If he had that level of knowledge he wouldn't be asking this question in the first place now would he? :)

Comment: @Déjàvu you are both absolutely right... Hence the ammendment

Comment: @kelevra Although you have an answer, please listen to JayBlanchard en JohnConde for future questions... First try something yourself!

Comment: I will! Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$value = date("j")=="5" ? "It's the fifth!" : "It's some other day";
```

`date()` is a function to print a date (by default the current date) and format it with format codes (letters). `j` is the format code for the day of the month. The `?` is a tenary operator, it is a shorter equivalent to doing this:

```
if(date("j")=="5") {
    $value = "It's the fifth!";
}
else {
    $value = "It's some other day";
}
```

Hope that you now understand how to do that!